# How to run remote image (Oracle Container Image) using kubectl in local machine?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, oracle12c, kubectl, minikube

I am using minikube and kubectl in my local machine. Now I need to run an oracle database with these. It can be any database.

Could you please let me know the way how I can run the oracle database on my local machine through minikube and kubectl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Plan A：

You can deploy oracle services in the form of submitting yaml files directly to k8s.

### Deploy

The following is the definition code of Oracle deployment.

This code consists of two parts, namely the deployment of Oracle deployment and its proxy service. The Oracle database deployed here is 11g r2, and the image used is `mybook2019/oracle-ee-11g:v1.0`. The two ports `1521` and `8080` are exposed through the NodePort mode, and the Oracle data is persisted through the `nfs` file system.

oracle-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oralce-svc
  labels:
    app: oralce
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    targetPort: 1521
    name: oracle1521
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: oralce8080
  selector:
    app: oralce
```

oracle-deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oralce
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oralce
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oralce
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mybook2019/oracle-ee-11g:v1.0
        name: oralce
        - containerPort: 1521
          name: oralce1521
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: oralce8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: oralce-data
          mountPath: /u01/app/oracle
      volumes:
      - name: oralce-data
        nfs:
          path: /home/sharenfs/oracle
          server: 192.168.8.132
```

Through `kubectl` execute the following command to deploy the Oracle database in the Kubernetes cluster.

```sh
$ kubectl create -f oracle-service.yaml
$ kubectl create -f oracle-deployment.yaml
```

After the deployment is complete, you can view the ports exposed by oracle through the following command (the ports here are `1521` and `32175`)

```sh
$ kubectl get svc
```

[image: svc]

### Check

For applications in the Kubernetes cluster, the relevant information for connecting to the database is as follows:

```sh
hostname: oracle-svc.default
port: 1521
sid: EE
service name: EE.oracle.docker
username: system
password: oracle
```

For the machine where the oracle client is located, execute the following command to connect to the database.

```sh
$ sqlplus system/oracle@//oracle-svc.kube-public:1521/EE.oracle.docker
```

For applications outside the Kubernetes cluster, the relevant information used to connect to the database is as follows:

```sh
hostname: 10.0.32.165
port: 32175
sid: EE
service name: EE.oracle.docker
username: system
password: oracle
```

For the machine where the oracle client is located, execute the following command to connect to the database.

```sh
$ sqlplus system/oracle@//10.0.32.165:32175/EE.oracle.docker
```

---

## Plan B:

Install by helm [chart](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/helm-charts/oracle-db/README.md)

To install the chart with the release name `db19c`:

Helm 3.x syntax

```
$ helm install db19c oracle-db-1.0.0.tgz
```

Helm 2.x syntax

```
$ helm install --name db19c oracle-db-1.0.0.tgz
```

The command deploys Oracle Database on the Kubernetes cluster in the default configuration. The configuration section lists the parameters that can be configured during installation.

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you could share details regarding what you've already tried in order to deploy an Oracle database on minikube, otherwise your question appears too generic.

For any application to be deployed on a kubernetes distribution like minikube -- you need the manifests of that application (in this case Oracle database) which would describe the desired state of the application.

You can then expose that application using a service & consume it.